# ASP.Net insert special character in button text

Tags: asp.net, button, symbols

Is it possible to display a special character like trademark on an ASP button control? if so, how do I do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use character map (press start, run and type charmap then enter) select the special character, copy to the clipboard and paste into the text property of the control.

Answer (score 5):

You can use html codes such as `&copy;` = © and `&#8482;` = ™ etc in the text property of your button.

For a more detailed list of these codes: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

example:

```
<asp:Button ID="tradeMarkButton" runat="server" Text="TradeMark&#8482;" />
```